# ssh-import-id failing with "ERROR local variable 'keys' referenced before assignment"

Tags: ssh, ssh-import-id

I am trying to understand whether this error is something I can fix or if it is a bug in ssh-import-id:

```
$ ssh-import-id gh:my-user-id
2017-12-08 04:46:58,282 INFO Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.github.com
2017-12-08 04:46:58,609 ERROR local variable 'keys' referenced before assignment
```

Edit: I am on a 16.04 distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a less helpful version of the following error message (which I received on a 14.04 distribution):

```
$ ssh-import-id gh:my-user-id
2017-12-08 13:18:38,890 INFO [0] SSH keys [Authorized]
2017-12-08 13:18:38,891 ERROR No matching keys found for [gh:my-user-id]
```

So you probably don't have any keys associated with that GitHub account! After adding keys to my account, I received the much more encouraging message:

```
$ ssh-import-id gh:my-user-id
2017-12-08 13:24:16,021 INFO Authorized key ['2048', 'REDACTED', 'my-user-id@github/12345678', '(RSA)']
2017-12-08 13:24:16,024 INFO [1] SSH keys [Authorized]
```

Comment: Btw, the distribution version of ssh-import-id has a bug that only imports a single key from GitHub: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ssh-import-id/+bug/1565275